# simple_form association not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a simple_form that is building my form for `ResponseSet`. A response set is basically collection of responses to a questionnaire (which has_many questions). A question can have many answers. (It's complicated, I know). When attempting to render out the radio buttons for answers to a particular question, none of the radio buttons get selected even though there are answers related to this response. Changing the `as:` to `:check_boxes` seems to work correctly. Is this a bug w/ SimpleForm?

```
= simple_form_for @response_set do |rs|
  = rs.simple_fields_for :responses do |r|
    - if r.object.question.class <= Question::SingleChoice
      = r.association :answers, as: :radio_buttons, collection: r.object.question.answers, label_method: :text, label: false
```

**response_set.rb**

```
class ResponseSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :responses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :responses
end
```

**response.rb**

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_and_belongs_to_many :answers
  belongs_to :response_set
  has_many :questions,
    through: :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end
```

**questionnaire.rb**

```
class Questionnaire < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :response_sets
end
```

**answer.rb**

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :responses
  belongs_to :question
end
```

**question.rb**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :responses,
    through: :answers
  has_many :answers
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `:selected` option to the association. For example:

```
= r.association :answers, 
  as: :radio_buttons, 
  collection: r.object.question.answers, 
  label_method: :text, 
  label: false, 
  selected: r.object.question.answers.select {|ans| ans.responses.any? }
```

Also, if you need to build a lot of questionnaires/surveys (especially if they're complicated), I'm a huge fan of the [surveyor gem](https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor), even though their default CSS is ugly.